# Ajax could not find controller when port number not provided in url on apache server

Tags: ajax, spring, apache, same-origin-policy

I am new in Spring mvc and i don't have much idea on this. My problem is like this,I have a jsp page with an ajax in it..the url i m passing in ajax goes through a controller.when i m running the application on apache server,the url could not find the controller and render the view.The other part of the application is working fine even when I don't provide a port number in the url but the ajax could not call the controller.How ever when i provide port number in the url,the controller is called..I really dnt ve idea with this.

example

`www.example.com/spellingcorrection` does not find controller spellingcorrection.

`www.example.com:8080/spellingcorrection` finds the controller and everything is working fine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does your apache configuration contain any `ProxyPass` rules - or mod_jk rules - that would forward port 80 to port 8080 for specific paths?

Comment: @WillKeeling yes it does...any suggestions?

Comment: Are there proxy rules in place for the URL path used by the AJAX requests? If not, the AJAX requests will have to use port 8080 explicitly - as there will be no way for them to reach the app server behind Apache.

Comment: @WillKeeling,no there is no any proxy rules defined by me for the URL path in the ajax.Should i define it,if yes how could i proceed?Is there any other alternative as well?

Comment: Could you post your Apache configuration for the `ProxyPass` rules? We may be able to tell you what extra config you'll need to support your AJAX requests.

Comment: what about using "curl" or "wget". on both ajax and non ajax url. alternatively, just disable port 8080 and use mod_jk with apache httpd?